# How does a large resistor in parallel with a thermistor affect the voltage-temperature graph curve?

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance, voltage, electronics

I want to know whether my understanding of the thermistor being in parallel with a large fixed resistor is correct. There is another resistor in parallel with the thermistor but that is fixed and not changed at all.

[image]

So if you increase the resistance of the resistor in parallel with the thermistor, the current going through that resistor will decrease because in a parallel circuit, the voltage is constant in both branches. Thus current is inversely proportional to the resistance. With the current decreasing through the fixed resistor, this must mean there is more current going through the thermistor. With more current, there is more heat being transferred through the wires which will affect the temperature of the thermistor and will therefore create an uncertainty in the reading of the thermistor.
HOWEVER, what I don't understand is if the current is increasing through the thermistor, and the thermistor itself is being added to boiling water, then the resistance of the thermistor will decrease and the current will further increase? Is this the correct understanding?

Answer (score 0):

A large resistor parallel to the thermistor is not going to do much at all. It will very slightly decrease the measured voltage, but that's it.

The current through the thermistor can indeed heat up the thermistor but in most cases that's a small effect since you try to keep the current through the resistor small.

> and the thermistor itself is being added to boiling water

In this case the temperature of the thermistor is determined by the boiling water. Even if the current through the thermistor generates extra heat, this extra heat is immediately dissipated into the water.

Whether you need correct for self heating of the thermistor depends on it's thermal environment. A thermistor in free air can indeed heat itself (since air is a really good insulator) but in most practical cases a thermistor will be thermally well coupled to the thing you want to measure (like a PC board, surface, or liquid), and in this case the measured object will just absorb the little extra heat from the thermistor.